# Array Formula Not Working in VBA - Recorded Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to speed up a spreadsheet with a lot of array formulas by recording a macro and applying the formula to those cells, then copy and paste as values. I get the "Run-time error 1004: Unable to set the FormulaArray proprety of the Range Class".

I am trying to do a reconciliation between two sets of data: Sheet"CA Tax Spreadsheet" and "XSP Events". I am using an array formula to search for the information in columns C and D together in CA Tax Spreadsheet tab in the XSP Events tab and vice versa. I then want to list all the information that doesn't match. I then use another array formula to list all of the exceptions while skipping blanks (i then use this information to grab information from other columns to display nicely on another sheet). This means there are four columns with array formulas: FORMULA 1 COLUMN A - showing the items in CA Tax Spreadsheet that aren't in XSP Events, FORMULA 2 COLUMN B- showing the items in XSP Events that aren't in CA Tax Spreadsheet, FORMULA 3 COLUMN C - showing all the items missing in XSP Events without blanks and FORMULA 4 COLUMN D - showing all the items missing in CA Tax Spreadsheet without blanks. These formulas all get dragged down to row 1000, which slows down the spreadsheet drastically. There are also formulas on SHEET1 which perform an INDEX MATCH on the information provided in COLUMNS C/D, grabbing information from columns C-F in CA Tax Spreadsheet and XSP Events. Because of this I tried to record a macro and apply the formulas this way, then copy and paste the values to try and speed it up. The macro crashes on FORMULA 1. I do not have much experience with Macros nor arrays so if there is a better way to speed up what I am doing please let me know.

```
Sub Macro_TEST1()
'
' Macro_TEST1 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Calculations").Activate
    Range("A2:A1000").FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(OR((AND(('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[5]=""M""),('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[8]<TODAY()))),(AND(('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[5]=""V""),('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[7]<TODAY()),ISNUMBER('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[7]))),('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[6]=""ADR Foreign Tax"")),"""",IF((ISNUMBER(INDEX('XSP Events'!C:C[13],MATCH(1,((TEXT('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[2],0))='XSP Events'!C[2])*('CA T" & _
        "ax Spreadsheet'!RC[3]='XSP Events'!C[3]),0),1))),"""",'CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[3]))" & _
        ""
    Range("B2:B1000").FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(ISNUMBER((INDEX('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!C1:C10,MATCH(1,((VALUE('XSP Events'!RC[1]))='CA Tax Spreadsheet'!C[1])*('XSP Events'!RC[2]='CA Tax Spreadsheet'!C[2]),0),1))),"""",IF('XSP Events'!RC[2]="""","""",'XSP Events'!RC[2]))"
    Range("C2:C1000").FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(C1, SMALL(IF(LEN(C1)=0,"""", ROW(C1)-MIN(ROW(C1))+1), ROW(RC[-2]))),"""")"
    Range("D2:D1000").FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX(C2, SMALL(IF(LEN(C2)=0,"""", ROW(C2)-MIN(ROW(C2))+1), ROW(RC[-3]))),"""")"
    Sheets("Reconciliation").Activate
    Range("A6:E1000").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(Calculations!R[-4]C3="""","""",INDEX('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!C[2],MATCH(Calculations!R[-4]C3,'CA Tax Spreadsheet'!C4,0)))"
    Range("H6:1000").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(Calculations!R[-4]C4="""","""",INDEX('XSP Events'!C[-5],MATCH(Calculations!R[-4]C4,'XSP Events'!C4,0)))"
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

The macro crashes here:

```
Range("A2:A1000").FormulaArray = _
        "=IF(OR((AND(('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[5]=""M""),('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[8]<TODAY()))),(AND(('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[5]=""V""),('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[7]<TODAY()),ISNUMBER('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[7]))),('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[6]=""ADR Foreign Tax"")),"""",IF((ISNUMBER(INDEX('XSP Events'!C:C[13],MATCH(1,((TEXT('CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[2],0))='XSP Events'!C[2])*('CA T" & _
        "ax Spreadsheet'!RC[3]='XSP Events'!C[3]),0),1))),"""",'CA Tax Spreadsheet'!RC[3]))" & _
        ""
```

I've tried applying it separately or just to 1 cell and it still does not apply. The other formulas are applied without issue.

Comment: The limit of FormulaArray is 255 characters.

Comment: The first formula has over 400 characters

Answer (score 0):

As @Scott Craner alread mentioned, there is a limit of 255 character for a formula array in vba.

You should set

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

at start and

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

at the end.

You need to set dummy-strings for parts of the formula array (`'CA Tax Spreadsheet'!` -> `xx`) and write this edited formula-array to a cell. Afterwards you use the worksheet function (!!!) replace (`cell.replace`) to replace the dummy-strings with their original values.

This way you can circumvent the 255 character limitation of formula array in vba.